# DDMS invisible after Eclipse upgrade Luna to Mars

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms, eclipse-mars

I updated Eclipse Luna to Mars. Now my DDMS perspective has invisible entries when I attach my phone. I can click on them and enable debugging but they have no labels. How can I fix this?

Comment: I would guess DDMS has not been tested with Eclipse Mars yet and needs to be modified.

Comment: Is this bug tracked anywhere?